# One application for different weighbridges?

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

I have a WPF application which connect to a weighbridge to get the weights.

```
spWeigh = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.Even, 7, StopBits.One);
            spWeigh.RtsEnable = false;
            spWeigh.DtrEnable = false;
            spWeigh.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            spWeigh.ReadTimeout = 10000;
            spWeigh.DataReceived += spWeigh_DataReceived;

spWeigh.Write(((char)5).ToString());


void spWeigh_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
 strResponseWeigh = spWeigh.ReadLine();
            if (strResponseWeigh.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBoxWrapper.Show("Error in communication with weighbridge", "Error");
                return;
            }
string wt = strResponseWeigh.Substring(15, 6);
}
```

I need to use the same application with a different weighbridge. Then I need to change the code for the weighbridge as below:

```
 spWeigh = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        spWeigh.RtsEnable = false;
        spWeigh.DtrEnable = false;
        spWeigh.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        spWeigh.ReadTimeout = 10000;
        spWeigh.DataReceived += spWeigh_DataReceived;

  void spWeigh_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            strResponseWeigh = spWeigh.ReadLine();
            if (strResponseWeigh=="")
            {
                MessageBoxWrapper.Show("Error communicating with the weighbridge", "Error");
                return;
            }

//Some more checking are to be done here depending on the response(different from the first weighbridge type)

 string wt = strResponseWeigh.Substring(2, 7);
}
```

Is it possible to make the weighbridge section generic? All that we do is send a character(or characters) to weighbridge, get the response, check whether the response is valid and read the weights.

Is it possible to do a config file so that we change some values in this file depending on the weighbridge without changing the actual code?

Comment: Yes, it's possible - what are you struggling with? I did exactly this (wrote a `WeighBridge` component) for a previous employer. Not sure why you've tagged this WPF as it should have nothing to do with UI.

Comment: Hi Kent,

I will be checking a different substring for each weighbridge and the message shown will be different in each case. Can this be done?

Could you please explain briefly how to go about it.

Comment: My point is that you should have a UI-agnostic component that detects these failures and raises an event. Then the consumer of that component can decide what to do in case of failures. A UI might display a message box, but you might want a service to log the problem. The detection of errors and the handling of them are separate concerns, and you should design the code accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most elegant way to manage this would be to encapsulate the SerialPort object in a class with properties that configures this object.

To store values in a configuration file, you can set values in the config.app file and access values with the [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class

Answer (score 0):

You could put all your dynamic values (e.g. Timeout, Com-Port-No ... ) in a config file as you already stated. You can use the app.config file for this or your own XML-formatted file.

Another approach could be a Strategy Pattern implementation, see [link](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx)

Your methods and events (Connect, Disconnect, DataReceived) would be defined in the strategy base class, which describes the algorithm, the implementation itself is covered in the derived strategies.

For maximum flexibility you could also use the config file in combination with a strategy pattern, especially when you want to support more than 2 weighs and different weighing algorithms in the future.
E.g. Weigh Type A and B should weigh with strategy 1, Weigh Type C and D with strategy 2.

Answer (score 0):

[image: static class diagram]

I think you need something like what's in this uml.  In the WeighMachine class (abstract) you define something like a WeighingReceived event, and hold a reference to another abstract, WeighMachineConfig.  Your application code only deals with the abstract WeighMachine (use a factory to select and instantiate the correct instance from config).  Each weigh machine can have different config parameters as well as a different commands to send to it so the config should be encapsulated in the WeighMachineConfigX classes and the protocol/commands in the WeighMachineX classes.  When the concrete weigh machine instances receive data, they should invoke the public event defined on the abstract WeighMachine class.